# Best way to split a string that has titles in it

Tags: python, split

here is my string :

```
data = '2.5 Excavation et terrassement 2.7 Travaux d'emplacement 3.2 Petits ouvrages de béton 4.2 Travaux de maçonnerie non structurale marbre et céramique 5.2 Ouvrages métalliques 6.2 Travaux de bois et plastique 7 Isolation étanchéité couvertures et revêtement extérieur 8 Portes et fenêtres 9 Travaux de finition 11.2 Équipements et produits spéciaux 12 Armoires et comptoirs usinés 13.5 Installations spéciales ou préfabriquées 15.6 Propane 17.2 Intercommunication téléphonie et surveillance'
```

i want the result to be:

```
list = ['2.5 Excavation et terrassement', '2.7 Travaux d'emplacement', '3.2 Petits ouvrages de béton',...]
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: Why is `'2.5 Excavation et terrassement'` repeated in the result? What have you tried?

Comment: the first input is a string that contains bunch of sub-titles that start with numbers, the output is the result i want each title separated from the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
print(re.findall(r'\d[\d.]*\D+[^\s\d]', data))
```

Explanation:

- `\d[\d.]*` will match a digit followed by any number (zero included) of digits and dots
- `\D+` will match one or more non-digit characters
- `[^\s\d]` ensures the match doesn't end with a space (equivalent of stripping) or a digit (that would belong to the next title)

###### Edit: this is not fool-proof since any digit occurring in a title will be recognized as the start of a new title (hardly avoidable since you have title # like 8 or 9...)

Comment: you're welcome! please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I'm new to this platform i just discovered how to do it , it done !

Answer (score 1):

You could use re.split() to process the space preceding a number as your separator:

```
import re
print(re.split(r' (?=\d)',data))
```

*The `(?=\d)` part is a look-ahead that ensures that only spaces that are followed by a digit will be treated as separators.*

output:

```
['2.5 Excavation et terrassement', 
 "2.7 Travaux d'emplacement", 
 '3.2 Petits ouvrages de béton', 
 '4.2 Travaux de maçonnerie non structurale marbre et céramique', 
 '5.2 Ouvrages métalliques', 
 '6.2 Travaux de bois et plastique', 
 '7 Isolation étanchéité couvertures et revêtement extérieur', 
 '8 Portes et fenêtres', 
 '9 Travaux de finition', 
 '11.2 Équipements et produits spéciaux', 
 '12 Armoires et comptoirs usinés', 
 '13.5 Installations spéciales ou préfabriquées', 
 '15.6 Propane', 
 '17.2 Intercommunication téléphonie et surveillance']
```